# DI in Java without annotations?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Is there any way (existing framework) to configure DI in Java without having to add annotations to classes where they "don't belong"?

In my research, it looks like to accomplish constructor injection we need to add some annotation to the constructor, like this:

```
@Inject // or @Autowired for Spring Boot
public MyInjectedClass(IThing1 thing1, IThing2 thing2) { ... }
```

Spring Boot also suggests adding `@Service` to implementations in order to register them with DI for injection.

Adding these annotations brings DI into the injected class (`MyInjectedClass` and any controllers, service implementations, etc.). Those classes should have no concept of DI, they should just be given the things they ask for in the constructor and not care about *how* they got there.

I know you can use the `@Configuration` attribute in Spring Boot, but this still feels not very configurable or powerful. Is there any way to accomplish this using Java without annotations? E.g. like how SimpleInjector, AutoFac, etc. work in C#? (Configured via code, not XML or config files, and not via annotations.)

If not, I'm curious why such a different approach has been taken between Java and C# in regard to DI.

**Update** I've offended someone in the comments but that was not my intent at all. I am asking a legitimate question. Let me highlight my concern/question in another way.

Suppose I have the following packages/classes. I have marked each case where each type of DI will appear. By "appear" I mean these marked classes/packages have some relation to the DI framework being used.

> **[A]**: annotation-based DI (3rd party package dependency)
>
> **[C]**: configuration-based DI

- data_access **[A]**

  - repositories

    - PersonRepository **[A]**
- logic **[A]**

  - people

    - CreatePersonCommandHandler **[A]**
    - UpdatePersonCommandHandler **[A]**
- services **[A]**  **[C]**

  - controllers

    - PersonController **[A]**  **[C]**

I hope this helps to illustrate my true question. The footprint of annotation-based DI extends into the far reaches of the stack, whereas configuration-based DI is only used in the outermost (entry) application, where the composition root lives.

Comment: Gotta tell them sometime, somehow.  It's a style choice.  When Spring was first invented it was all done in external XML files.  Annotations were added as a choice later on.  Now the pendulum has swung entirely in the direction of annotations; I'm not aware that Spring Boot supports XML anymore.

Comment: @duffymo Don't get me wrong, I definitely don't want to configure DI via XML! That sounds awful. I'd rather use annotations, but that feels like it's less-good than configuring DI externally via code.

Comment: You sound like you don't want either.  Like I said, you have to tell the DI factory somehow.  If you don't like XML or annotations, how do you propose doing it?  What does C# do that's so much better in your view?

Comment: I'm not suggesting it's better or worse, just curious why annotations are used over config via code. E.g. in C# we'd usually have a `DependencyInjectionConfig` class which registers dependencies such as `container.Register<IService, IImpementation>();` -- registers which implementation should be injected for which service.

Comment: Spring supports configuration in form of Java code: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_java_based_configuration.htm

Comment: I do that with some dependencies in Spring Boot, but it's a mix with other classes that I just use the annotations.  I have no idea what you're complaining about.

Comment: Not complaining, but you are introducing DI-specific annotations deep in your stack where DI is not a concern. Why should your _repository_ implementation care that is registered as a service in DI? It shouldn't; DI is the concern of the composition root, not the services it composes.

If I have my repositories in a separate package, now I need to add a dependency to Spring Boot (for instance) into that package which otherwise has no need for DI at all.

Doesn't this violate _separation of concerns_ and add dependencies where they shouldn't be needed?

Comment: @duffymo so is there a way to register dependency without any annotations, anywhere (and without xml of course)?

Comment: I'm not a DI zealot.  I add the annotations and sleep at night.  I don't see a situation where I'm going to change DI engines or forego them completely.  I can't muster much outrage for violating separation of concerns.

Comment: "Avid C#/.NET software engineer" - I have better things to do than finding other languages and bashing them for not being my preference.

Comment: @duffymo Sorry if I offended you. My question is legitimate. I haven't used Java in many years and am getting back into it now after using C# for 15+ years. I'm just curious about the differences in approach. I'm not suggesting Java is doing something wrong, I'm asking why it is this way, in this case. I have no idea why you seem so defensive about this -- they are just programming languages.

Comment: @JoshM., did you ever find DI solution in Java that does config via code?  I'm in the same situation as you were last year.  I just switched from C# to Java and don't understand why I'd want to hard wire annotations throughout the code.

Comment: @Josh It can be done. You can define an `@Configuration` class/bean. You can create a method here for every dependency you'd like to inject. Then you can forego the `@Service`, etc. annotations deep within the stack. I'd say it is way more work to do this, and also it's not pretty bulky compared to the C# method I mentioned. But it's doable.