# Configure auto-wired service injection with "code"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, configuration

I've posted [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49557522/di-in-java-without-annotations), but I need to elaborate with an example to get a useful answer.

I am not sure, using Spring Boot, how to define a specific instance of a class which Spring should use to inject into `@Autowire`d dependent fields/constructors.

Suppose I have a utility class which is in a library which I either a) don't have access to change, or b) do not want to add a dependency on Spring Boot to.

**SecurityUtil** -- takes in two string arguments which would likely come from some application-level config (defined in an external package).

```
public class SecurityUtil {
    private final String algorithm;
    private final String key;

    public SecurityUtil(String algorithm, String key) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**PasswordHelper** -- uses `SecurityUtil` to sign a password (for example).

```
public class PasswordHelper {
    private final SecurityUtil securityUtil;

    @Autowired
    public PasswordHelper(SecurityUtil securityUtil) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

During application startup, I want to be able to create a singleton instance of `SecurityUtil` using the algorithm and key defined in my application's configuration (or elsewhere). I assumed that I would be able to add a class similar to the one below, but I'm not sure how to configure the injection of my singleton.

**DIConfig** -- configure things for DI (e.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class DIConfig
{
    @Value("${security-util.key}")
    private String securityUtilKey;

    @Value("${security-util.algorithm}")
    private String securityUtilAlgorithm;

    public void configure(SpringDiMagicalConfig config)
    {
        // register a singleton SecurityUtil instance
        config.register(new SecurityUtil(securityUtilKey, securityUtilAlgorithm));
    }
}
```

How can I accomplish this configuration using Java / Spring Boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go this way:

```
@Component
public class DiConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityUtil securityUtil(
            @Value("${security-util.key}") String securityUtilKey,
            @Value("${security-util.algorithm}") String securityUtilAlgorithm) {
        return new SecurityUtil(securityUtilKey, securityUtilAlgorithm);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. After applying that change, the app won't start and gives the following error. I assume it's an issue with order in which things are being configured: "LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext"

Comment: @JoshM. can you update your question with your changes and the full stacktrace, please

Comment: My mistake, I had my injected (`@Value`) variables mixed up -- applied a default value to the wrong one, and left the other out of the config. So the real exception was that there was no config entry found for one of those variables.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the `configure` method with:

```
@Bean
public SecurityUtil securityUtil()
{
    return new SecurityUtil(securityUtilKey, securityUtilAlgorithm);
}
```